# Регулярное выражение или удаление подстроки - что работает быстрее?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Имеется, например, регулярное выражение:

```
Pattern regexPhone = Pattern.compile("^(\\+?\\d+)?\\s*(\\(\\d+\\))?[\\s-]*([\\d-]*)$");
```

Проверяет валидность номера телефона. Также есть вариант поиска подстроки в строке, и ее удаление, для получения валидного номера телефона, в качестве альтернативы. Например, функцией replaceAll. Понятно, что и тот, и тот способ отработает быстро, но все же, какой из них по факту будет работать быстрее по времени? ) Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос возник сейчас, когда нет возможности проверить это на компе.

Comment: Сколько номеров обрабатывается за раз?

Comment: Один номер.

Comment: @impe, у вас даже возможности почувствовать разницу нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, нужно измерять. Но можно сказать, что значительной разницы вы не увидите, т.к. `replaceAll` сам по себе использует регулярки:

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```